# equivalent to push() or pop() for arrays?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add, remove and reference items from an array I create in my main java file, but I am having trouble figuring out the correct syntax.  In actionscript they have push() and pop() for adding and removing items in an array, is there an equivalent in android?

Comment: What kind of array do you have? Can you show us some code?

Comment: int [] intArray = new int{2, 3, 5, 8, 13};
how would i reference intArray[3], or all items one at a time?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Java an array has a fixed size (after initialisation), meaning that you can't add or remove items from an array.

```
int[] i = new int[10];
```

The above snippet mean that the array of integers has a length of 10. It's not possible add an eleventh integer, without re-assign the reference to a new array, like the following:

```
int[] i = new int[11];
```

In Java the package java.util contains all kinds of data structures that can handle adding and removing items from array-like collections. The classic data structure Stack has methods for push and pop.

Comment: Good explanation, however keep in mind that Stack isn't that great of a class as it inherits from Vector, and as such is fully synchronized. So unless you need the synchronization, ArrayList or LinkedList is likely a better option.

Answer (score 25):

For those who don't have time to refactor the code to replace arrays with `Collection`s (for example `ArrayList`), there is an alternative. Unlike `Collection`s, the length of an array cannot be changed, but the array can be replaced, like this:

```
array = push(array, item);
```

The drawbacks are that

- the whole array has to be copied each time you push, and
- the original array `Object` is not changed, so you have to update the variable(s) as appropriate.

Here is the `push` method for `String`:
(You can create multiple `push` methods, one for `String`, one for `int`, etc)

```
private static String[] push(String[] array, String push) {
    String[] longer = new String[array.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        longer[i] = array[i];
    longer[array.length] = push;
    return longer;
}
```

This alternative is more efficient, shorter & harder to read:

```
private static String[] push(String[] array, String push) {
    String[] longer = new String[array.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, longer, 0, array.length);
    longer[array.length] = push;
    return longer;
}
```

Comment: I strongly discourage the use of this method. For really simple and small arrays it won't impose problems, but for a medium or heavy array this will cause the system to iterate over the array every time an item is added. If you have a 100+ items array and want to add more 3 items, it will do 303 operations.

Answer (score 22):

Use Array list
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: No idea why this is the accepted answer. The right answer is java.util.ArrayDeque or java.util.LinkedList

Comment: @Rotem I think you can easily find the reason here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452672/java-howto-arraylist-push-pop-shift-and-unshift

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Arrays.copyOf()` with a little reflection to make a nice helper function.

```
public class ArrayHelper {
    public static <T> T[] push(T[] arr, T item) {
        T[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
        tmp[tmp.length - 1] = item;
        return tmp;
    }

    public static <T> T[] pop(T[] arr) {
        T[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length - 1);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
String[] items = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};

items = ArrayHelper.push(items, "d");
items = ArrayHelper.push(items, "e");

items = ArrayHelper.pop(items);
```

**Results**

> **Original:** a,b,c
>
> **Array after push calls:** a,b,c,d,e
>
> **Array after pop call:** a,b,c,d

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf()` creates new array each time it's called. If you have to pop quite a long array in a loop, performance will be much worse than `for (...) {String stringC = stringA + stringB}`

Answer (score 6):

You can use LinkedList. It has methods peek, poll and offer.