# java howto ArrayList push, pop, shift, and unshift

Tags: java, arraylist, terminology

I've determined that a Java `ArrayList.add` is similar to a JavaScript `Array.push`

I'm stuck on finding `ArrayList` functions similar to the following

- `Array.pop`
- `Array.shift`
- `Array.unshift` I'm leaning toward `ArrayList.remove[At]`

Answer (score 186, accepted):

[`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is unique in its naming standards. Here are the equivalencies:

```
Array.push    -> ArrayList.add(Object o); // Append the list
Array.pop     -> ArrayList.remove(int index); // Remove list[index]
Array.shift   -> ArrayList.remove(0); // Remove first element
Array.unshift -> ArrayList.add(int index, Object o); // Prepend the list
```

Note that `unshift` does not *remove* an element, but instead *adds* one to the list. Also note that corner-case behaviors are likely to be different between Java and JS, since they each have their own standards.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of "unshifting" but not a lot of getting at middle indices, you may find ArrayList to be inferior to LinkedList in terms of actual run times.

Comment: while(Item item = items.remove(0)){ ... } is not equivalent to shift.

Comment: What about `.push`?

Comment: OP said he knew `Array.push -> ArrayList.add`, and specifically asked about `pop`, `shift`, and `unshift`. Reading this again, I'm going to add more explanation and add `.push` at the same time.

Comment: Even though it was not asked, this answer feels incomplete without any mention of the complexity of these functions.

Comment: This is subjective an may thus be flagged, but it is less efficient for ArrayLists to have different method names then their analogous counterparts in similar languages because programmers will have to repeatedly search up or take time to learn the new method names and may even be more liable to write code with logical errors. Objectively, it is dumb.

Comment: @Cozzbie that is not true in the case of ArrayList.remove(int index) which the answer references since this overload does return the object removed.

Answer (score 35):

I was facing with this problem some time ago and I found [`java.util.LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is best for my case. It has several methods, with different namings, but they're doing what is needed:

```
push()    -> LinkedList.addLast(); // Or just LinkedList.add();
pop()     -> LinkedList.pollLast();
shift()   -> LinkedList.pollFirst();
unshift() -> LinkedList.addFirst();
```

Comment: Why is this not accepted?! Note: `LinkeList` adds methods which would be very inefficient on `ArrayList`  to the `List` interface, this was what confused me. This methods come from the `Deque` and `Queue` interfaces which it implements, but `ArrayList` does not.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 but how much inefficient?

Comment: @Slava O(n) vs O(1) for front insert, which is huge.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 O(n) and O(1) are just complexities. I heard that linked lists can be quite slower than array lists even for inserts/deletions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170566/bjarne-stroustrup-says-we-must-avoid-linked-lists So I wonder, what about Java?

Comment: This is not a solution. a linked list is simply a different data structure with different characteristics. This questions pertains to a contiguous list

Comment: This is not a solution. a linked list is simply a different data structure with different characteristics. This questions pertains to a contiguous list

Answer (score 15):

maybe you want to take a look `java.util.Stack` class.
it has push, pop methods. and implemented List interface.

for shift/unshift, you can reference @Jon's answer.

however, something of ArrayList you may want to care about , arrayList is **not** synchronized. but Stack is. (sub-class of Vector).  If you have thread-safe requirement, Stack may be better than ArrayList.

Comment: Stack extends vector which is synchronized. ["Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Comment: My bad, I just realized that in my sleep deprived state I didn't read the last half.

Answer (score 6):

Great Answer by [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8452709/7384648).

I'm lazy though and I hate typing, so I created a simple cut and paste example for all the other people who are like me. Enjoy!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> animals = new ArrayList<>();

        animals.add("Lion");
        animals.add("Tiger");
        animals.add("Cat");
        animals.add("Dog");

        System.out.println(animals); // [Lion, Tiger, Cat, Dog]

        // add() -> push(): Add items to the end of an array
        animals.add("Elephant");
        System.out.println(animals);  // [Lion, Tiger, Cat, Dog, Elephant]

        // remove() -> pop(): Remove an item from the end of an array
        animals.remove(animals.size() - 1);
        System.out.println(animals); // [Lion, Tiger, Cat, Dog]

        // add(0,"xyz") -> unshift(): Add items to the beginning of an array
        animals.add(0, "Penguin");
        System.out.println(animals); // [Penguin, Lion, Tiger, Cat, Dog]

        // remove(0) -> shift(): Remove an item from the beginning of an array
        animals.remove(0);
        System.out.println(animals); // [Lion, Tiger, Cat, Dog]

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library contains methods push(values), pop(), shift() and unshift(values).

Code example:

```
import com.github.underscore.Underscore:

List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("one", "two", " three");
List<String> newStrings = Underscore.push(strings, "four", "five");
// ["one", " two", "three", " four", "five"]
String newPopString = Underscore.pop(strings).fst();
// " three"
String newShiftString = Underscore.shift(strings).fst();
// "one"
List<String> newUnshiftStrings = Underscore.unshift(strings, "four", "five");
// ["four", " five", "one", " two", "three"]
```