# How to delete a particular thing from a list?

Tags: java, list

For the implementation of an algorithm,I need to delete a particular value from the list.

**Eg:---**

My list:---

```
     Ist row->4,7,3,4

     IInd row->2,8,6,5

     IIIrd row->3,5,1,7
```

Before delete some values,I need to sort it.That is,

```
     Collections.sort(list);
```

**Sorted Result**

```
     2,8,6,5

     3,5,1,7

     4,7,3,4
```

**Expected OUTPUT**
Now I need to delete 1st elements of all rows. The output is

```
     8,6,5

     5,1,7

     7,3,4
```

How I do this???I tried it by using tokenizer method,but I don't get it.

Comment: What data structures are you using for each row?

Comment: are you maybe looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452672/java-howto-arraylist-push-pop-shift-and-unshift

Comment: Each row is actually a string.

Comment: @Dahlia..can u provide more code of how you are storing your list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the first element from a java.util.List with

```
myList.remove(0);
```

To eliminate the first *space delimited word* (or number) from a string, use:

```
s = s.substring((s.indexOf(" ") + 1), s.length());
```

Note that this will fail if the string is null, or does not contain a space.

You can protect against this with

```
if(str == null || str.indexOf(" ") != -1)  {
   throw  new IllegalArgumentException("str (" + str + ") must be non-null, and must contain a space.");
}
//Safe!
str = str.substring((str.indexOf(" ") + 1), str.length());
```

Comment: It is deleting the Ist row.I need to delete a particular value from the row,not the entire row.

Comment: Updated again. Thank you for the up-vote and acceptance!

Answer (score 1):

You just delete the list item at zero position...
Like this

```
 ListVariable.remove(0);
```

For the every First element means Use for loop...
Just get the Rows...

```
for(int i =0 ; i<ListVariable.size() ; i+4 )
{
      ListVariable.remove(i);
}
```