# type mismatched from int to ArrayList

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I need some help. I am currently programming about polymorphism, and here was the stipulation for my homework. I am willing to take advice on how to do it.

**Stipulation of the homework:**
Write a method that removes the duplicate elements from an array list of integers using the following header:

public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList list)

Write a test program that prompts the user to enter 10 integers to a list and displays the distinct integers separated by exactly one space. Here is a sample run:

Enter ten integers: 10 20 30 20 20 30 50 60 100 9

The distinct integers are: [10, 20, 30, 50, 60, 100, 9]

**Here is my code so far:**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayInput extends ArrayList{
public static int a[];

public static int[] inputArrays(int a[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        a[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    return a;
}

public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(a[i] != a[i--] ) {
            list = a[i];
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You're reassigning the arraylist to an int element every time the 'if' condition succeeds. Instead, 'add' the element to the arraylist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452672/java-howto-arraylist-push-pop-shift-and-unshift

Comment: The best thing to would be to check for duplicates as you read them. To check for duplicates in an unsorted list you have to look through the whole list, the code you have will only remove duplicates next to each other. Another bug is that you initialize i to 0 then check i--, so you're going out of bounds and changing i at the same time, making it so your loop never terminates

Comment: Hint: `if(a[i] != a[i--] )` is not what you want.  You go through the loop incrementing `i` by 1 each time, but this statement will decrease `i` by 1, so you're back where you started and you will end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: Your required signature is terrible, you shouldn't use raw types.

Comment: Extending `ArrayList` is completely unnecessary.  What you really want here is for `a` to be an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of an `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert or cast array of int to ArrayList but if you want to add elements to list, you can do something like this:

```
public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(a[i] != a[i--] ) {
            //change code here
            list.add(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 list = a[i];
```

I think this is where your problem is, you're trying to assign an *int* value to an *ArrayList*.