# push a new item into the end of the array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

So I want to Push a new item onto the end of the array (the numbers 1-9).  I was told by a friend that the code I have written is correct, but when I run it on eclipse, nothing happens.  What do I need to do? Should I just print the array under the main block? thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
}

public static long[] push(long[] array, long item) {

    // Add one item to an array
    long cellsToAdd = 1;
    long[] array2 = new long[array.length + 1];

    // copy each item in array2 -> array3
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array2[i];
    }

    array2[array2.length - 1] = item;

    System.out.println("Array: ");
    // Print the array to the console
    for (long p : array2) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }

    return array2;
}
```

Comment: you're not calling the function

Comment: you should call `push` from the main method.

Comment: Note also that Java arrays have fixed length.  You *can't* push anything onto the end.  The code you present instead creates a new, longer array with the desired contents.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that, but it's important to appreciate the difference between that and what you asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [equivalent to push() or pop() for arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537980/equivalent-to-push-or-pop-for-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.arraycopy` to create a new array and increase its size.

Since you are using the primitive `long` type, you would need to copy-paste this logic for each primitive (`int`, `float`, `double`, etc) if you want to support these types.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] digs = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5 }                       
    long[] digs2 = push(digs, 6);
    long[] digs3 = pushAll(digs2, new long[] { 7, 8, 9 });

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digs));   // [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digs2));  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digs3));  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    // Generic Example
    Long[] genArr = push(new Long[] { 0L, 1L }, new Long(3L), Long.class);

    // or Long[] genArr = push(new Long[] { 0L, 1L }, new Long(3L));

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(genArr)); // [0, 1, 3] 
}
```

## Push

```
public static long[] push(long[] a, long b) {
    long[] result = new long[a.length + 1]; 
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length); 
    result[a.length] = b;
    return result;
}
```

## Push All

```
public static long[] pushAll(long[] a, long[] b) {
    long[] result = new long[a.length + b.length]; 
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length); 
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length); 
    return result;
}
```

## Generic Push

```
public static <E> E[] push(E[] a, E b, Class<E> classType) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E[] result = (E[]) Array.newInstance(classType, a.length + 1);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length); 
    result[a.length] = b;
    return result;
}
```

## Optional

```
// Convenience, so that you don't have to pass in the class.
public static Long[] push(Long[] a, Long b) {
    return push(a, b, Long.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from actually calling the function like others mentioned, your for loop copys from array2 to array, while it should be the other way around

Answer (score 0):

## Call the method

You defined a method but did not call it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    array = MyClassName.push( array , 10L );
}
```

If you are merely practicing to learn, well enough. But know that this kind of functionality is already provided for you in the Java Collections framework.