# Ballerina appending elements to end of an array

Tags: arrays, ballerina

How can i append element to end of an array directly other than using following code.

```
string[] array = ["1","2"];
array[lengthof-1] = "3";
```

Comment: Bellarina? What's that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [equivalent to push() or pop() for arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537980/equivalent-to-push-or-pop-for-arrays)

Comment: It a Cloud Native Programming Language. https://ballerina.io/

Comment: I don’t get it, their page says you draw stuff and it works but then it comes back and shows yet another brick of code.

Comment: Ballerina (https://ballerina.io/) is a cloud-native programming language. It is a general-purpose programming language that is better suited for network data such as JSON, XML, tables with first-class abstractions that'll ease your microservices and other applications development that involve integrations with network services.  Here is the language specification. https://ballerina.io/res/Ballerina-Language-Specification-WD-2018-05-01.pdf. Examples guide https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/

Answer (score 4):

Here is the only possible way at the moment.

```
   int[] a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
   a[lengthof a] = 7;
```

There is no built-in append function at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a function for that.

```
function append(int[] arr,int val){       
arr[arr.length()] = val;
}
```

Then you can use it in your code